Can you still use a namespace prefix if you type out "using namespace x"
If you typed
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Hello.\n"; // Is this ok?
    return 0;
}


Can you still use the namespace prefix without errors?

Try it…………………..

Sorry I didn't know

But also, using using namespace std; is not recommended. And use using namespace with care.  Watch : C++ Weekly - Ep 305 - Stop Using using namespace

It is perfectly valid. The using namespace std; directive does not override or interfere with explicit namespace qualification.
However, it is better to avoid broad usage of using namespace. That way, you write cleaner, more maintainable, and less error-prone code, especially in larger projects.
